# Take multiple inputs using loop in array using matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to take multiple inputs at once using a for loop using array in matlab.

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
}
```

I could I perform that in matlab?

Comment: Looking for [`input`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/input.html) maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Try reading about `input`.

`doc input`

**Example from doc**

Request a text response. Assign a default value ('Y') by checking for an empty matrix.

```
reply = input('Do you want more? Y/N [Y]: ', 's');
if isempty(reply)
    reply = 'Y';
end
```